# HTML5 rel not validating

Tags: jquery, html

I have a basic jquery tabbed box script on an html5 document, but this `rel=""` :

```
li rel="tab1"
```

is throwing off the validation...

The jquery is...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".tab_content").hide();
    $(".tab_content:first").show(); 

    $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
        $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(".tab_content").hide();
        var activeTab = $(this).attr("rel"); 
        $("#"+activeTab).fadeIn(); 
    });
});
```

Could I just replace the `rel` with another attribute ??

Many thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "throwing off the validation"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend using `data` attributes.

E.g.

```
<li data-target="tab1"></li>

$(this).data('target');
```

Comment: `rel` has a specific, well-defined set of values in HTML5. That's why it doesn't validate here. Surprise! You can't just give it any value you want - that's what `data` attributes are for.